# Use of pdftricks with memoir

Tags: memoir, verbatim, pdftricks

below is a (long, non-working) minimal example for use of pdftricks with the memoir document class.  It is based directly on the (shorter, working) minimal example of use of pdftricks found at http://www.tug.org/pipermail/macostex-archives/2009-June/040498.html.  I get an error as follows:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\psinputs ->\verbatimwrite 
                           {tmp.inputs}
l.28   \begin{psinputs}
```

Any help is appreciated!

```
\documentclass[article, a4paper, 12pt, twoside]{memoir}

\setlrmarginsandblock{23mm}{23mm}{*}
\setulmarginsandblock{23mm}{28mm}{*}
\setheadfoot{\onelineskip}{2\onelineskip}
\setheaderspaces{*}{1mm}{*}
\checkandfixthelayout
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{1}
\setsecindent{1cm}
\let\footruleskip\relax % for compatibility of memoir and fancyhdr
\let\sl\ttfamily        % for compatibility of memoir and blindtext (silly, but it works) ha ha \ttfamily
\let\sc\scshape
\let\bf\bfseries
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyfoot{}
\cfoot{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
%%% End of memoir stuff

\usepackage{ifpdf}
\ifpdf%
  \usepackage{pdftricks}
  \begin{psinputs}
    \usepackage{pstricks}
    \usepackage{pst-plot}
    \usepackage{pstricks-add} % <- added this line!
  \end{psinputs}
\else
  \usepackage{pstricks}
  \usepackage{pst-plot}
  \usepackage{pstricks-add} % <- added this line!
  \newenvironment{pdfpic}{}{}
\fi

\begin{document} 
\centering
\begin{pdfpic}
\begin{pspicture}(-1,-1)(6,6)
\psaxes[showOriginTick=false,showorigin=false,Dx=2,Dy=2,subticks=2](6,6)
\end{pspicture}
\end{pdfpic}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Why do you want `fancyhdr` compatibility? Memoir can do all that stuff itself...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `\DisemulatePackage{moreverb}` to the preamble, btw: you can reintroduce `\sc` using the `oldfontcommands` class option

Answer (score 2):

use the package `auto-pst-pdf`instead of `pdftricks`. It really simplyfies the use of PSTricks:

```
...
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}
\usepackage{pstricks-add} % <- added this line!

\begin{document} 
\centering

\begin{pspicture}(-1,-1)(6,6)
\psaxes[showOriginTick=false,showorigin=false,Dx=2,Dy=2,subticks=2](6,6)
\end{pspicture}
...
```

run it as usual with `pdflatex -shell-escape <file.tex>`

Comment: nice suggestion, I'll try it when I get closer to final draft status.  for the moment, installing auto-pst-pdf and all its dependencies is a bit heavy -- I'm using texlive 2007, no tlmgr :(.

Comment: ok, that is really old ... You can try to run `pst2pdf`. It is a Perl script, which extracts all PostScript specific part of your doc and creates single pdf images which then are used in a last pdflatex run. The script is available from CTAN.